# How to modify the Dataframe as below in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on R for a Data Analysis. I have a Dataframe which stores the data for each month in a Year. For certain months of a particular year the data is missing. The dataframe which i am currently using is as below.

[image]

How to modify the data in the Dataframe to be stored in another dataframe in this below manner?

[image]

The column Year is of the type yearmon and n is of the typr int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

##Recreate data
df <- tibble(
    Year = c("Dec-13", "Jan-14","Feb-14","Mar-14",
             "Apr-14", "May-14","Jun-15","Jul-14",
             "Aug-15","Sep-18"),
    n = c(1,8,2,4,8,9,2,1,1,1)
)

##convert to character, spread, and fill

df_2 <- df %>%
mutate(Year = parse_character(Year)) %>%
separate(Year, into = c("Month", "Year")) %>%
mutate(Year = paste0("20",Year)) %>%
spread(Year,n, fill = "-") %>%
mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = c("Dec","Jan","Feb", "Mar","Apr",
                                        "May","Jun","Jul", "Aug",
                                        "Sep"))) %>%
arrange(Month)


df_2
```

Comment: This is Awesome :) Thank you so much ! This is as expected !! 

When the Month values are getting printed.. they are not getting printed in the correct order... For example like Jan, Feb, March, etc... they are getting printed in the Alphabetical order. Is there any way to overcome this please.

Comment: Hello, If I need to calculate the Total Numbers (i.e. Sum of data) for each year. Is it possible in the Same code ? Can you please help me. When i tried doing it i am very unsuccessful in Obtaining the results.